# Message shown to OP when their question is closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, wording

[Group keys into same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355219/group-keys-into-same-object) was closed as a duplicate. A few minutes later the OP opened an identical question [Put the objects together given key with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355448/put-the-objects-together-given-key-with-same-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I closed that as a duplicate of the first, and told him that he should have edited the original question with more details, to explain why it wasn't a duplicate. He explained that the text in the close explanation says

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

This is presumably only shown to the OP, since I don't see it there. This advice doesn't seem appropriate, I thought the general process to deal with inappropriate closures is to edit the question to resolve the close reason; then it will go into the reopen queue. Why does the message say to ask a new question?

Comment: See [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401721/4642212) and [“You can edit the question or post a new one”](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/4642212).

Comment: The OP sees a different message than everyone else: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325955/282094 - The OP is first asked to "edit this question to explain how it is different **or** ask a [mine: *different*] **new** question" - Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz4AG.png

Comment: @Rob That's not what I see for this question, which is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: It just says: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: Barmar, I guess that concludes the "Discussion" tag, and this is a bug; as (ironically) advised in the duplicate please edit your question to explain how it is different (as your [prior comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372977/message-shown-to-op-when-their-question-is-closed-as-a-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment1245496_372977) explains), tag it as a bug (instead of discussion) and it will automatically enter the reopen queue - which I will vote on, if it comes to me. This is [what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UwXJ.png).

Comment: I'm just leaving it closed as a duplicate, I upvoted the linked question.

Comment: It appears that you agreed that it's a correct duplicate, and I don't disagree, but the other question is 9 years old (the user interface and banner have been changed more than once during that period of time) and it's fair to ask again after so long; more recent duplicates are still more than a few years old. --- Entirely up to you, to leave it or edit it.

Comment: That question really confuses me, since there's an answer saying it was changed, but comments saying it's back to the old text, and that's what I see.